# Conditional References in a JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to write a single file JSON schema definition with several sub schemas that I can combine, depending on the payload.

The following schema validates, that my schema is working with my sample JSON response. (The response object has a wrong type for `payload.role` to make sure the schema catches this mistake!)

For clarity, I reduce it on the most important parts. A full working example can be found here: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/3KAaXjtg

**Schema**

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "http://example.com/baseSchema.json",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "payload"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "payload": {
      "$id": "#/properties/payload",
      "type": "object",
      // reference the right schema depending on the payload child key
      // if `payload.user` reference `userSchema.json`
      // if `payload.users` reference `usersSchema.json`
      // if `payload.*` reference `*Schema.json`
      "$ref": "userSchema.json"
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "user": {
      "$id": "http://example.com/userSchema.json",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "user"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "user": {
          "type": "object",
          "$ref": "userProperties.json"
        }
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "$id": "http://example.com/usersSchema.json",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "users"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "users": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "userProperties.json"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "userProperties": {
      "$id": "http://example.com/userProperties.json",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "firstName": {
          "$id": "#/properties/payload/properties/user/properties/firstName",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Response**

```json
{
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "description": "User retrieved successfully."
  },
  "payload": {
    "user": {
      "firstName": "Joe",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "role": "3", // for testing reasons, this is the wrong type!
      "email": "doe@example.com",
      "customerID": "",
      "projects": [
        "AIXG5mEg6QLl9rhVSE6m",
        "Bs1bHiOIqKclwwis3CNf",
        "NC2OUGVZXU35FA7iwRn4"
      ],
      "status": "Status",
      "id": "c555BSZnKLdHSRYqrU5hqiQo733j13"
    }
  }
}
```

So I've got a `baseSchema.json` that matches this response:

```json
{
  "status": {},
  "payload": {}
}
```

`payload` gets extended by a certain key like `payload.user = {}` or `payload.foo = {}` and depending on that key, I want to extend schema with one of my definitions.

The following part only works for the key `user`:

```json
  "properties": {
    "payload": {
      "$id": "#/properties/payload",
      "type": "object",
      // reference the right schema depending on the payload child key
      // if `payload.user` reference `userSchema.json`
      // if `payload.users` reference `usersSchema.json`
      // if `payload.*` reference `*Schema.json`
      "$ref": "userSchema.json"
    }
  },
```

I failed to setup any [conditions](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html) (with `allOf`, `if`, `else`), that would reference the correct sub-schema, based on the `payload` key.

Any hints and help to solve that is appreciated.

Comment: Are the conditions mutually exclusive or not? Either way, the solution is similar, but without kowing, the solution may not work for you

Comment: @Relequestual They are exclusive. only one *Schema.json can be referenced. The solution is similar to what?

Comment: Regardless of your answer, the solution (that I'll provide) is similar

Comment: Ah... follow up question, do you know all the possible keys in advance? This cannot be done dynamically.

Comment: Yes, the possible keys are known. I was hoping for a dynamic solution, but I can see that this doesn't make sense in this context of a static document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schema and link to demo at the end... Let's look at how we got there...

In JSON Schema draft-07 and previous, you can't use `$ref` alongside other keywords. Other keywords are ignored. (In your schema `http://example.com/userSchema.json` you had `type` next to `$ref`). Fortunatly this didn't cause you any problems as you declare the type in the referenced schema. (You CAN do this with 2019-09 or above.)

The values for the keywords `if`, `then`, and `else` are schemas.
For the `then` subschema to be applied to your instance location, the `if` schema must come back as valid. If it fails, the `else` subschema value will be applied.

Our if condition checks for the presense of a specific key.
If the key exists, THEN apply the schema which references the correct schema.

Because you want the conditions to be mutually exclusive, you need to wrap the multiple conditions in a `oneOf`, and add `else: false` to the conditional checks. `false` as a schema makes validation fail.

Let me know if you want any further clarification on any of the above.

Demo: https://jsonschema.dev/s/HLniL

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "http://example.com/baseSchema.json",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "payload"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "payload": {
      "$id": "#/properties/payload",
      "type": "object",
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "required": [
              "user"
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "$ref": "userSchema.json"
          },
          "else": false
        },
        {
          "if": {
            "required": [
              "users"
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "$ref": "usersSchema.json"
          },
          "else": false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "user": {
      "$id": "http://example.com/userSchema.json",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "user"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "user": {
          "$ref": "userProperties.json"
        }
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "$id": "http://example.com/usersSchema.json",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "users"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "users": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "userProperties.json"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "userProperties": {
      "$id": "http://example.com/userProperties.json",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "firstName": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the example and explanation. It makes more sense, now that I see the conditions with my own data :). 
What I don't understand: In your example and in mine (https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/366lU11Y), the type error, I'm looking for, is listed along the errors from the condition. Can those be ignored?

Or is there a better approach to my problem?

Comment: You are welcome! Unfortunatly, there's no way to determine that you're trying to do what is effectivly switch sort of logic. Other similar specifications may call it a "discriminator", but such a thing doesn't exist in JSON Schema. If your schema IS written so those conditions are mutually exclusive, you should be able to parse the errors to determine which condition was met, but content of the schema failed, as the error path will include `then` rather than `else`. We are hopeful with standardised error formats, people might make stand alone tools for this sort of situation! 

Comment: So I guess my options are, either to write out everything, and/or merge schemas dynamically with JavaScript (I'm trying to use that in Postman ;-)).

Comment: You could use a tool like Jasonnet to construct your schemas dynamic elements into a static document, and then use the Postman API from within Postman to create or update your collection (or whatever).

Comment: You're going to get way better error messaging with the `dependencies` keyword, https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/JHEmWdby

Comment: For some reason I forgot you could use a schema value with those. Good call.